# combine min() and having()

Tags: t-sql

Is there any possibility to use something linke `having()` within a `min()` aggregate inline?

```
select distinct
  "timestamp"
  , MinActiveValue = min( "value" ) over ( partition by "timestamp" ) having ( "active" = 1 )
from
  "data"
```

In the linked example below, things work well using the first query.
Indeed, i don't want to have to use the where clause for min-condition, since i would destroy data-filtering used in the same query. ( there are some grouped sums calculated by the same query for example )

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53c12/8/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT
      timestamp
    , active
    , value
    , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY timestamp ORDER BY active DESC,value ASC )
  FROM
    data
)
SELECT timestamp, value AS MinActiveValue
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1 AND active = 1
```

Here you can apply your filter in the CTE itself.

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53c12/18/0)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't need `HAVING` for this. Just `GROUP BY "timestamp"` with `WHERE "active" = 1` like so:

```
SELECT
  "timestamp"
  , MinActiveValue = MIN( "value" )
FROM  "data"
WHERE "active" = 1
GROUP BY "timestamp";
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53c12/16)

Comment: as i already wrote, i can't use group by / where-condition, because i use both to filter my data on other ways. if i'd extend where-clause and group-by, my data, would be reduced...

Comment: @Nico - In your example there is no problem to use `WHERE` with a `GROUP BY` and it is the same as the query you posted. But can you please explain with some sample data how this can reduce your data and will destroy your data filtering?